# How to get log files sorted by date in Windows 8.1 app (QueryOptions give me an exception)?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt, windows-8.1-universal

In my windows8.1 app, I have some logs and I want to read them by time, I had code below

```
List<string> fileFilter = new List<string>();
        fileFilter.Add(".ERROR");
        StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, fileFilter);
        var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> filteredFiles = await query.GetFilesAsync();
        if(filteredFiles.Count > 0)
        {
            err = filteredFiles[0].ToString();
        }
        return err;
```

However, `new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderBySearchRank, fileFilter);` gives an not implemented exception. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the files using `GetFilesAsync()` on the folder and sort them by yourself.

Comment: But since MSFT provide this query method, why don't we use it? The interesting thing is that on another machine, it works...

Comment: When developing Windows Phone 8.1 they tried to make the API the same as on Windows 8.1 .. but they did not implement everything. There are many API that are there but are not implemented.

Comment: Do you know any API I can use here instead of QueryOptions? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing I can recall, you really have to do the seorting yourself

Comment: OK, thank you! Seems I have to sort it by myself then.